# How long does sys.dm_exec_sessions in SQL Server reach to the past?

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to have a look if there are any user accounts on a SQL instance not in use. So I took a look on sys.dm_exec_sessions.

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions order by login_time
```

sys.dm_exec_sessions seems to store only sessions from today (to be exact of the last few hours). Is this right? **Does anyone know what time frame is covered by sys.dm_exec_sessions?**

SQL Server 2017.

Comment: "what time frame is covered by sys.dm_exec_sessions" - zero. It is a view of sessions that currently exist not of historic ones

Comment: To validate @MartinSmith, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): *"is a server-scope view that shows information about all **active user connections** and internal tasks."* A connection that is closed isn't an active connection any more.

Comment: Note that due to client-side connection pooling, clients often leave connections open for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin Smith and Larnu commented:

**sys.dm_exec_sessions is not a history! sys.dm_exec_sessions shows only active (and not closed) sessions.**